# Efficiency reading chars of a file

Tags: c, performance, io, fseek

I train myself in building a compiler. When I read the file I sometimes need to look a few characters ahead of my current position to know which token I have to generate.

There are two options that come to my mind in that case:

- I read the entire file first and access the characters with an index variable
- I read one char at the time with `getc(file);` and in case I have to go back to some previous character I use `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);`

Which one of these options is more efficient? Which would you prefer?

Comment: The first has high startup cost, but is more efficient over the rest of the code. The second spreads the cost over the entire run of the program. Unless the source file is many megabytes, the difference will be negligible, so do whatever is most easy for you.

Comment: Note that stdio uses buffered I/O, so most of the time when you seek back it won't have to access the file on disk. It's essentially doing the same thing as the first option.

Comment: It may be more efficient to use [`ungetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) instead of `fseek`. However, on some platforms, you can only push back a single character.

Comment: @Barmar `doing the same thing as the first option`  function call overhead. I/O functions even if they read from the buffer are much more expensive than simple array access. But of course if it is done few times it does not matter.

Comment: @0___________ Many things in stdio are implemented as macros to avoid the function call overhead when possible.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: According to [§7.21.9.2 ¶4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p4), `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);` will invoke undefined behavior on text streams. However, this will not be a problem on POSIX-compliant platforms, because POSIX defines the behavior. On non-POSIX platforms, you can call `ftell` and then `fseek` back to that position later.

Comment: I also written some compilers (including a C one). Using `getc` is not a good idea. It is slow and not flexible for writing a compiler. The former alternative is fine if the source code is small. It is still not very flexible but better. If you want a maintainable solution, please consider using *ranges*. They will make the code far simpler so you can then focus on optimization easily (rather than maintainability). Working on chunks is the best solution but it generally make the code unreadable. Ranges are not very fast but they succeed to be close to the speed of the code of Clang.

Comment: Maintainability is critical for complex compilers. Optimizing an unmaintainable compiler code is a nightmare and very bug prone, and tracking bugs in a complex compiler is also a nightmare ;) .

Comment: If you choose to read the entire file into a buffer, instead you could use `mmap` to get the buffer

Comment: The performance of `mmap` vary widely from system to system. MacOS comes into mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. My decision is to just read the file entirely first and then later check if I run into any performance issues.